# Loop multidimensional array in twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, twig

How do I loop multidimensional array in twig.

[image]

What I've tried is

```
{% for key, record in records %}

    {% for key1, record1 in record %}

         {{ key1 }}

     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

But I only get the index of array like so

- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 1
- 0
- 0
- 1

What I want is to get the value of `MoneyChanger` and `AddTransaction` Array. Like for example

- id
- name
- currency
- amount
- pieces

Answer (score 1):

I want to post my answer.

I manage to resolve the issue by

```
{% for key, record in records %}

     {% for key1, record1 in record %}

           {% if record1.client is defined %}   

            {{ record1.id }}

           {% endif %}

     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```